# jinja2 variable won't update as expected in a loop based on operation performed

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I am setting jinja2 variable outside (before) the loop, yet it is being resetted every time the loop is being iterated.

I have this following code:

```
{% set c = 0 %}
{% for n in n_list %}

    {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}

    {% else %}
        {% set l = range(3, 6) | random %}
        {% set c = c+l %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ loop.index }} {{c}} {{l}}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

it returns:

```
1 3 3
2 4 4 # expected: 2 7 4
3 0   # expected: 2 7 0
4 4 4 # expected: 2 11 0
5 5 5 # ...
6 0 
7 5 5
8 5 5
9 0 
10 4 4
```

Comment: value in  >> n_list<<??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on unsupported behavior that worked in Jinja <=2.8 but stopped working when the scoping system was improved/fixed in Jinja 2.9.

See the [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/641) and the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments). Both places mention possible workarounds - and it's very likely that a future Jinja version will contain [new](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/676) [functionality](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/684) to make this easier.

---

If none of the currently available options work for you you can always abuse mutable objects for this (of course this is quite ugly):

```
{% set c = [0] %}
{% for n in n_list %}
    {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}

    {% else %}
        {% set l = range(3, 6) | random %}
        {% set __ = c.append(c[0] + l) %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ loop.index }} {{ c[-1] }} {{ l }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because of the way variable scoping works in Jinja2. [Source](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments)